# How to insert a dynamic form values into database in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to insert form values(dynamic checkbox,input) dynamically into database
This my view file:

```
<form action="<?php base_url('controller/insert'); ?>"> 
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>Menu Id</th> 
                <th>Menu Name</th> 
                <th>Yes/No</th> 
            </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($result as $res) { ?>
                <tr> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="menu_id[]" value="<?= $res->menu_id ?>"></td> 
                    <td><input type="text" name="menu_name[]" value="<?= $res->menu_name ?>"></td> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="yes[]" value="<?= $res->menu_id ?>"></td> 
                </tr> 
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

this my controller function:

```
<?php
    $fields = array(
        'menu_id'   => $this->input->post('menu_id'),
        'menu_name' =>  $this->input->post('menu_name'),
        'yes'       =>$this->input->post('yes')
    );
    $this->db->insert('menu_table',$fields);
?>
```

when i print this array $fields it displays as:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => Plant [1] => Line ) Array ( [0] => on [1] => on ).
```

this my form:the menuid and menu desc and checkbox displaying dynamically.i need to insert into table as same as the form below displays.
[image]

Comment: Do you get an error? Are wrong values inserted? Is anything inserted?

Comment: you have to loop through your post value then insert the data since all form values are in arrays

Comment: no, i'm not getting any error,but i want to insert into db like the image mentioned above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through the arrays. You can use the menu id as the key as it is sequential e.g. the first of `menu_id` corresponds with the first of `menu_name`:

```
$menu_id = $this->input->post('menu_id');
$menu_name = $this->input->post('menu_name');
$yes = $this->input->post('yes');

$yes = is_null($yes) ? array() : array_flip($yes);

if (is_null($menu_id) || is_null($menu_name)) {
    show_error('Parameters missing');
}

// should really be in a model
foreach ($menu_id as $key => $value) {
    $data['menu_id'] = $value;
    $data['menu_name'] = $menu_name[$key];
    $data['yes'] = isset($yes[$value]) ? 'true' : 'false';
    $this->db->insert('menu_table',$data);
}
```

Comment: can you check something for me? your checkboxes are returning 'on' in your example. as you may know if a checkboxes isn't checked then it doesn't submit **anything** hence it might mess up the order and be incorrectly assigned in my answer. according to your value it should return the value of the menu_id? but it doesnt???

Comment: in any case if you can get the checkboxes to report the menu_id when checked you can simply modify my code as follows: `$yes = array_flip($this->input->post('yes'));`

Comment: but warning error occurs Message: array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: my bad `$yes = $this->input->post('yes'); $yes = is_null($yes) ? array() : array_flip($yes);`

Comment: but if the checkbox isn't checked it stores false into table.(i replyed :can you check something for me?)

Comment: shouldn't that be the case? why would you want it to store true if it isn't checked.. whats the point?

Comment: now it stores false only. it doesn't stores true when checkbox is selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176547/discussion-between-alex-and-sunshine).